# Convergence of a series with the summands changed by a factor of log?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Suppose we have a non-negative function $f$. Suppose we have that the series
$$
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} f(n)
$$
converges. I was wondering does it then follow that
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}f(n) \log n
$$
converge as well? My guess is that there should be a counterexample for this but I have not been able to construct one. Any comments appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take $f(n)=\dfrac1{\log^2(n)}$, because$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\log^2(n)}$$converges, but$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\log(n)}$$diverges.